# SVN keywords based on filetype

Tags: svn, version-control, revision

I am using subversion to track a set of files and would like to carry the revision keywords through the workflow. But I'm running into some issues due to the way this is set up.

The workflow follows this format:

1. Text file (svn:keywords enabled) which gets imported into an;
2. Xml type file that contains the keywords imported from the text file. This script then gets run and spits out another;
3. Xml type file that ideally contains the revision information of both 1&2.

The requirements for the file revisions are 1 < 2 < 3 and the revision of 1 displayed in 2 and the revisions of 1 & 2 are displayed in 3.

So the problem arises at file 2 where I obviously cannot have svn:keywords enabled as this will overwrite the entry from file 1 when it is committed.

Ideally I'd want to have different keywords dependant on the file type, but this doesn't seem to be possible in SVN.

I have looked into pre/post-commit hooks but from my understanding without allowing different keywords, these wouldn't help.

I have thought of a possible solution where I'd enter some keywords in file 1 that are intended to be unique for file 2. Then when I commit file 2, I'd write a little script that looks for those keywords and fills those entries with similar information (I.e. pre-empt the revision number by checking the repository revision number, add one and put that in file 2 then commit it). However, this requires external scripts which are not an issue to develop but I'd like to keep it in house with SVN if possible.

Is there any way to achieve this using SVN alone?

To be clear, I don't want or care about having the revision number of file 3 within the file, as long as the revisions of files 1 & 2 are present.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to figure out this special case. In the overarching folder I set the svn:auto-props for the two file types, e.g.
*.txt = svn:keywords=Revision Author
*.xml = svn:keywords=XMLRevision=%r XMLAuthor=%a
Now I have both sets of keywords in the first file, where the first set gets picked up by the commit of the txt file and the second gets picked up by the xml commit. Both sets are displayed in the third file too.
Note: it was possible to set auto-props from the repo browser, but it didn't seem to work. Checking out the overarching folder and doing it from the working copy did the trick.
Note 2: obviously also had to delete the file 2 (xml) from the repo and add it again for it to pick up the new auto-props.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid, but it seems you made some wrong assumptions and didn't debug your workflow

- Even in old pre-1.8 SVN (which added "custom keywords", which *can* emulate keyword-per-filetype), which I anyway **do not recommend** to use today expanded keywords, pasted into another versioned object will not be "expanded" again
- With 1.8+ SVN you *can* have set of keywords with different names, but the same value `%r`, but it just not needed in your case

Details:

When you add keyword `$Rev$` into versioned file (and perform correct `svn propset svn:keywords` or have expanding enabled in config), after commit/update cycle you'll see in your WC in file something like `$Rev: 12 $` instead of *just keyword placeholder*, and this string, pasted in any other source, will be used "as is", not as one more keyword placement in target file

Comment: Thanks for the info Lazy Badger! That does clarify a few things in my knowledge. However, the specific case I have (from the workflow above) requires that the keywords for the file 2 must be embedded in file 1. So it seems that I can use custom keywords for the 2 file types and have both the "standard" keywords for file 1 and the custom ones in file 2. I've tried to do this using svn:auto-props, but can't seem to get the custom keywords to work for the 2nd file (they don't even show up when I check what properties the file has). Yes, I've removed/added the 2nd file to enable to new auto-props.